# Unnamed Style that can be used with BasedOn in UserControls

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am looking for a XAML-only way to define an unnamed style in a particular Window that affects all TextBoxes, even those inside UserControls.

Here is an example: suppose I have one particular Window in which I want to set the Foreground property to Red for all TextBoxes, including those contained in UserControls. I am trying to do it like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="300"
        SizeToContent="Height">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="A-Regular"/>
        <TextBox Text="B-Bold">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <local:MyUserControl/>
        <TextBox Text="C-Regular"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The used UserControl looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="Like A, but in UserControl"/>
        <TextBox Text="Like B, but in UserControl">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The resulting window is:

[screenshot of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6MvY.png)

Everything is OK, except for the TextBox "Like B, but in UserControl", which is bold and black. I would have expected to see red text, like in all other TextBoxes.

Is there a way to have the unnamed style in the Window's resource affect all TextBoxes in the UserControl, even those that expand the current TextBox's style using [BasedOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon)?
I am looking for a way where I do not have adapt all places where I "call" the UserControl (i.e. where I have `<local:MyUserControl/>` in the Window). Nor do I want to have to adapt the UserControl itself, because it might be within a third-party library.

Comment: You need to reference the `Style` in `MyUserControl.xaml` as well, just as you did in `MainWindow.xaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `Style` into `<Application.Resources>`